# Finding all Pythagorean triples less than 500

Tags: c++

I need to make a program that finds all Pythagorean triples for a, b, and c to 500. Here's my code:

```
int main()
{
    for (int a = 1; a <= 500; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 1; b <= 500; b++)
        {
            for (int c = 1; c <= 500; c++)
            {
                if ((a*a)+(b*b) == c*c && c <= 500)
                {
                    cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << c << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My for statements check for every value in c, then b, then a. So my problem appears to be within the if statement. It checks to see if a squared and b squared are equivalent to c squared. That's fine. Something interesting happens after the and statement, though. If I make it c*c <=500, I get a significantly shorter list of smaller numbers than if c < 500. However, if use c < 500 then the program starts in the 200s and goes up, missing obvious triples like 3+4=5. I'm curious why this happens, because obviously I'm not printing every triple for every value.

Edit: Okay, obviously the difference in c and c*c is huge but I used c*c to test what was weird about the program, sorry for not being clear. Also, removing the and statement presents the same problem. I don't understand why the program in its current state starts in the 200s rather than at 3+4=5. Here's the current output:

```
208 + 306 = 370
208 + 390 = 442
209 + 120 = 241
210 + 72 = 222
210 + 112 = 238
210 + 176 = 274
210 + 200 = 290
210 + 280 = 350
210 + 416 = 466
...
```

Comment: You are asking why your list is shorter when you limit `c * c <= 500` as opposed to `c < 500`?  That should be fairly obvious ...

Comment: The test `c <= 500` in the `if` condition is redundant as the `for` loop already guarantees this is true. I don't understand why this code would miss `3^2+4^2 = 5^2`, could you explain or show the output? And of course you get less results for `c*c <= 500`. This condition is obviously more restrictive.

Comment: Well, obviously if you start in the 200s you will mis 3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2?

Comment: Code looks fine. c * c <= 500  is equivalent to c <= 22,  hence you get less output

Comment: If you want to find the whole list, I would recommend removing the condition after `&&`. The problem here is that you are restricting your list so that the value of c*c should always be less than 500 which means that c could take values less 23

Answer (score 1):

Like other people have said, your code prints the correct values and doesn't just start from over 200.

208 + 306 = 370

I think your problem is the output overruns your available screen buffer. Hence at the top, you'll see it starting at 208 + 306 = 370.

Try writing the result to a file.

```
#include<fstream>
ofstream myfile("results.txt");
for (int a = 1; a <= 500; a++)
{
    for (int b = 1; b <= 500; b++)
    {
        for (int c = 1; c <= 500; c++)
        {
            if ((a*a)+(b*b) == c*c && c <= 500)
            {
                cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << c << endl;
                myfile << a << " + " << b << " = " << c << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
myfile.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code as such works fine for me. As in it does not miss any triplet.

However, I think you can make this more efficient (`O(n^2logn) instead of O(n^3)`) by eliminating the for loop for c. Just calculate `a^2 + b^2` and conduct a binary search for this number in a pre-built list of squares of numbers up to 500.

Of course this will require O(n) additional memory space.

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the entire loop over `c` and a good part of the one over `b`. We only need to test `b` in a range starting with the current value of `a` [*preventing from printing the same triplet twice*] and ending at `sqrt(500^2 - a^2)` [*because `c` won't be `<=500` for larger `b`'s*]. I give a solution in Java, which should be no problem to adapt:

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class Pythagorean {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   for (int a=1; a<500; a++)
    for (int b=a; b<Math.sqrt(250000-a*a); b++)
     if (Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b) == Math.round(Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b)))
      System.out.println(""+a+"² + "+b+"² = "+(int)Math.round(Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b))+"²");
  }
}
```

Output:

```
3² + 4² = 5²
5² + 12² = 13²
6² + 8² = 10²
7² + 24² = 25²
8² + 15² = 17²
9² + 12² = 15²
9² + 40² = 41²
10² + 24² = 26²
11² + 60² = 61²
12² + 16² = 20²
[...]
300² + 315² = 435²
319² + 360² = 481²
320² + 336² = 464²
325² + 360² = 485²
340² + 357² = 493²
```